# jQuery append not working with &nbsp;

Tags: jquery, json

I have some json that I am trying to use to generate a select box

The json has some elements in it that use `&nbsp;` to provide some spacing, for example.

```
[
  {"value":1, "text":"1"}
  {"value":2, "text":"&nbsp;1. a."}
  {"value":3, "text":"&nbsp;&nbsp;1. a. i."}
]
```

Then from my jQuery, I get those values and replace the options using .append().

```
$.each(response, function(id, ob) {
  // Add json results
  options.append($('<option>', {
    value: ob.value,
    text: ob.text
  }));

  // Apply
  $('#select_list').html(options.html());
});
```

However, when it shows up in the HTML, it is showing the `&nbsp;` instead of rendering an actual space.

I can modify either the jQuery or the json data, whichever one will allow me to add whitespace where required, but I am not sure how.

Comment: you inserted the html using the text method. `&nbsp;` in text form is rendered as `&nbsp;`. Note however that by using .html instead, it's going to insert whatever was returned. Only do this if you trust the server you're getting this data from, or, properly sanitize it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're wanting to insert html, not text:

```js
  $('select').append($('<option>', {
    value: "foo",
    text: "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text" // literal text
  }));


  $('select').append($('<option>', {
    value: "bar",
    html: "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;html" // parsed html.  (Sanitize it!)
  }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
</select>
```

Comment: Not at all, I get caught by that one more often than I should admit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{"value":3, "text":encodeURIComponent("&nbsp;&nbsp;1. a. i.")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside `&nbsp;` being a HTML representation - therefore you need a `.html()` instead of `.text()` (as already noted), here are some other ways to achieve the appending

```js
var response = [
  {"value":1, "text":"1"},
  {"value":2, "text":"&nbsp;1. a."},
  {"value":3, "text":"&nbsp;&nbsp;1. a. i."}
];

$.each(response, function(id, ob) {
  $('<option/>', {
    value: ob.value,
    html: ob.text,
    appendTo: '#select_list'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_list"></select>
```

```js
var response = [
  {"value":1, "text":"1"},
  {"value":2, "text":"&nbsp;1. a."},
  {"value":3, "text":"&nbsp;&nbsp;1. a. i."}
];


$("#select_list").append(
  response.map(function(o) {
    return `<option value='${o.value}'>${o.text}</option>`;
  })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_list"></select>
```